# Store propertyvalues so that it can be used in other classes

Tags: c#, winforms

In a windows form project I have two classes: createTextDef and CreateTextFile

In the CreateTextFile class I have a constructor that looks like this:

```
public string Price { get; private set; }
public string Unlock { get; private set; }
public string Stock { get; private set; }

public CreateTextFile(string Price,string Unlock, bool stock)
{
    this.Price = Price;
    this.Unlock = Unlock;
    if (stock)
        Stock = "true";
    else
        Stock = "false";
}
```

In my createTextDef class I must use the properties that is being created in the CreateTextFile class constructor like this:

```
public void CreateSingle()
{
string path = Common.PathToTextFile + CreateTextFile.TextName;
string text = File.ReadAllText(Common.templatePath + "Text files\\"+ "File.txt")
    .Replace("10",    CreateTextFile.Unlock)
    .Replace("100", CreateTextFile.Price)
    .Replace("true1", CreateTextFile.Stock)

   File.WriteAlltext(path, text)
}
```

In the Form1 class I am calling the CreateTextFile:

```
private void GenerateFile_Text_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(single)
        createText = new CreateTextFile(price, unlockLvl, true);
}
```

However when I try to access these property values in the createTextDef class I only get empty values. When I call the CreateTextFile constructor in the Form1 class the values is gone when I try to reach it from the createTextDef class. I do not know how to proceed so does anyone know how I can make property values not disappear when I try to call them from another class?

To be more clear: I have 3 values that I should be replacing with other string values in the CreateSingle method but they all is just replaced with empty strings and therefore the textfile im creating is empty. When I call the CreateTextFile constructor I do not put in empty strings.

I would preferably not want to use static members.

Comment: Most important part of your question is missing. How and where are you trying to 'access' the properties? Show that part of the code which actually gives you the problem.

Comment: In the second code example I am trying to access the properties. The properties is created before I run this method but If I debug it the propertie values are all just empty strings in that method.

Comment: FYI, You don't need an `if` condition in your constructor, you can simply do: `Stock = stock.ToString().ToLower();`

Answer (score 1):

The most likely reason for the empty property values is that you are *setting* properties of an instance called `createText` in your `GenerateFile_Text_Click_1`, but in the `CreateSingle` method you are *reading* properties from a different instance called `CreateTextFile`.

The most likely resolution is to use the `createText` instance whose properties you assigned values to for your source when reading the information.

Note that I also reversed the order of your replacements since calling `.Replace(10)` will also replace the first two characters of the string `100`, which you were also using as a placeholder.

```
public void CreateSingle()
{
    string source = Path.Combine(Common.templatePath, "Text files", "File.txt");
    string dest = Path.Combine(Common.PathToTextFile, CreateTextFile.TextName);

    string text = File.ReadAllText(source)
        .Replace("100", createText.Price)
        .Replace("10", createText.Unlock)
        .Replace("true1", createText.Stock)

   File.WriteAlltext(dest, text)
}
```

Ideally, you might consider using more unique strings to represent your placeholders in the template, like `"[Unlock]"`, `"[Price]"`, and `"[Stock]"` to avoid the ambiguity in the `Replace` code. Then that line would look like:

```
string text = File.ReadAllText(source)
    .Replace("[Unlock]", createText.Unlock)
    .Replace("[Price]", createText.Price)
    .Replace("[Stock]", createText.Stock)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The templatefiles placeholders was planned to be changed to more unique strings but it was not my highest priority. I see now how using the default values "10" and "1000" could generate erros.
Using the same instance did solve the problem. Thank you